# Work permit length on IEC Canada using a renewed passport

Tags: canada

My application in IEC program to work in Canada was recently approved. 
The passport I used with my application expires in September 2020. I clearly understood that my work visa will be granted only while my passport is valid.

There is the possibility of renewing my passport on September 2019, as it will be during its last year of validity. The new passport will be probably be valid for ten years.

If I use my renewed passport to enter Canada by, lets say January 2020, will the work permit be granted for a whole year until January 2021 or it will be granted until September 2020, as the passport used on its application expires on such date?
Note that I intend to use the new passport to enter Canada, not the old invalidated passport.